# Mule 4.3 Works fine when running in AnypointStudio but errors in docker-compose up

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Getting error in mulesoft. I searched for "transform" and "abstract-message-processor" in the xml and I cannot even find it.

```
mule_1  | + org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 95; columnNumber: 84;             +
mule_1  | + cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element      +
mule_1  | + '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core":transform}'. One of          +
mule_1  | + '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor,     +
mule_1  | + "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-pr +
mule_1  | + ocessor}' is expected.                                                       +
```

This is the xml namespace definition:

```
<mule xmlns:validation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation" xmlns:secure-properties="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-properties"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:oauth2-provider="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider" xmlns:oauth="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth" xmlns:os="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os" xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os/current/mule-os.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth/current/mule-oauth.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2-provider/current/mule-oauth2-provider.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-properties http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-properties/current/mule-secure-properties.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/validation/current/mule-validation.xsd">
```

In line 95, this is how it looks:

```
93--    <http:request-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP">
94--      <http:authentication >
95--        <http:basic-authentication username="#[payload.id]" password="#[payload.token]" />
96--      </http:authentication>
97--    </http:request-connection>
```

Comment: The error message mentions line 95. Please share that line of the XML.

Comment: I added where line 95 is. I did look at that line but nothing that seem to be related to the error. And I did not use the transform component.

Comment: Maybe the line count is off and it refers to some other line? Or even another file? Does the error message include any more details? Also, are you using the Enterprise Edition in Docker?

Comment: It's from this repo: https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone/

Is this an enterprise edition?

Comment: That's the community edition. See my answer below.

Comment: And which line numbers has each line of the snippet you shared.

Comment: I added the line in post above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240958/discussion-between-aled-and-alltej).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that when you are executing inside Studio with Mule 4.3.0 Enterprise edition, but when deploying outside you are using the Community Edition, which doesn't include any of the Enterprise features.

If you are not using any Enterprise features (for example the Transform component) inside the Mule XML file, then you can remove the `ee` namespace from the XML declaration and schema location:

```
<mule
...
 xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
...
 xsi:schemaLocation="...
...
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
...
/>
```

If your application is using any enterprise features you will need to remove or replace them.

Comment: Can I have a listener with GET that returns a json response without using the Transform component?

Comment: Yes, there are different ways to achieve that. Depends on what is the requirement. You didn't share any details of the application save for HTTP requester configuration. You did mention that there was not 'transform' in the application. Did you find one?

Comment: Just to return a static json response. Transform component and seems to be the ideal component but did not realized that this is not available for enterprise edition.

Comment: For a static JSON you can add the JSON as a file in the source project in the directory src/main/resources and read it in the flow with `<parse-template/>`

Comment: i added the static JSON. it works find in AnypointStudio but still does not work when running in docker. I checked the docker instance and I don't see the json file. Was wondering if the mule-maven-plugin are excluding these files by default when packaging it to jar file.

Comment: If it is the same issue, has you removed the Trasform component and the ee XML namespace? Or do you have a different issue and error? You should be more specific.

Comment: issue is different. i remove the use of Transform component. the parse template component cannot find the json file. i went inside docker container and there was no json file that i created. so i think issue is when maven package to jar file.

Comment: i figured that this is really just some caching. deleting the target folder and mvn clean package was not enough. i even have to delete the docker images did not even do it. i have to invalidate caches in intellij idea and force a restart. after that, it worked. thanks for your help!